# Android scrollview layout to mimic iPhone

Tags: android, iphone

### Header1    Header2    Header3 ....

### myData1  | mydata1 | mydata1 |.....

### myData2  | mydata2 | mydata2 |.....

### myData3  | mydata3 | mydata3 |.....

### myData4 | mydata4 | mydata4  |.....

Hi,
I have written a few iPhone apps and I'm trying to re-write them for Android with the same look and feel.

The app generates a ballistic chart with column headers and rows of calculations that scroll.
I tried to post a screen shot but this system would not allow it.

I have been able to reproduce it manually in xml, but I can't figure out how to do it programmatically on the Android.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: `I have been able to reproduce it manually in xml, but I can't figure out how to do it programmatically ` - specifically, why?  And the "stupid" restriction is for good reasons.  Please read the FAQ.

Comment: I meant specifically why can't you figure it out programmatically?  What did you struggle with?  THe no images rule was introduced to stop spamming, of which there was a lot.